# 3D model rotation on HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Referring to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_KkHLimetQ), I can't seem to see the cube which is supposed to be here.

Code causes these 2 errors:

```
DEPRECATED: THREE.CubeGeometry is deprecated. Use THREE.BoxGeometry instead. three.min.js:634
Uncaught ReferenceError: materials is not defined
```

Code:

```
<title>My first three.js app</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="C:\Users\123303G\Desktop\Webpage\three.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\123303G\Desktop\Webpage\TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script>
    // Our Javascript will go here.
    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 500;

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
        controls.addEventListener('change', render);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
        scene.add(mesh); 

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1: 
One of your methods namely `THREE.CubeGeometry` is deprecated, which means you should switch it to what the error suggests: `THREE.BoxGeometry`.
Do:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100);
```

Instead of:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100,100,100);
```

See [Three.js referece](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/CubeGeometry)

Problem 2:
On the other error you have a typo.  Your're using `materials` instead of `material`.
Do:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
```

Instead of:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I believe you just need to remove the 's' of materials in this function call:

```
   var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials);
```

You have defined the variable "material", but not "materials", which is what the Uncaught ReferenceError means. And this error is the showstopper.