# THREE.BoxGeometry problems

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was trying to make a 3D Rubik's Cube but whenever I put

```
cubelets.push(THREE.Mesh(
THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100,10,10,10),
THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000})
))
```

in the code, I get this message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.fromBufferGeometry is not a function          Three.min.js:_____
```

I can't remember exactly what goes in the _____ space, but you get the point. The thing is, I haven't seen any other reports of this happening.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzztbdvu/

Comment: CubeGeometry is deprecated?  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075715/

Answer (score 7):

New New New! Make sure that you are using *new* before the functions.

```
cubelets.push(new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100,10,10,10),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000})
))
```

I made the same mistake.

Comment: and `new THREE.Mesh(...)`

Comment: and I made the mistake again! :l

Comment: and `new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(..)`